# Expanding Twitter sentiment analysis

Tags: python, twitter, nlp

The code below analyzes twitter sentiment: whether it is positive, negative or neutral. However, it is fairly inaccurate for many tweets such as if it includes "someone gave him a middle fingered saulte", I want to train the program to recognize that middle fingered implies disrepect, even though it includes the word salute in the sentence.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

import re
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from textblob import TextBlob

```
class TwitterClient(object):
    '''
    Generic Twitter Class for sentiment analysis.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Class constructor or initialization method.
        '''
        # keys and tokens from the Twitter Dev Console
        consumer_key = 'WHexAxkRn6uEJkzS2CKpeQejI'
        consumer_secret = 'fSxjGVM247YS6Y6BpkWXaIfr6ThXdoSUg2y0aR259vNXVPPfob'
        access_token = '915324744140025862-jnGvcTPkJHOObkeydiVburK8SdAngEk'
        access_token_secret = 'JGgkWI9Lq0rJU1K0C8JLplRnSrEuw8pj3anOlIsn3YdiO'


        # attempt authentication
        try:
            # create OAuthHandler object
            self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
            # set access token and secret
            self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
            # create tweepy API object to fetch tweets
            self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)
        except:
            print("Error: Authentication Failed")

    def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
        '''
        Utility function to clean tweet text by removing links, special characters
        using simple regex statements.
        '''
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())

    def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet):
        '''
        Utility function to classify sentiment of passed tweet
        using textblob's sentiment method
        '''
        # create TextBlob object of passed tweet text
        analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet))
        # set sentiment
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
            return 'positive'
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
            return 'neutral'
        else:
            return 'negative'

    def get_tweets(self, query, count = 30):
        '''
        Main function to fetch tweets and parse them.
        '''
        # empty list to store parsed tweets
        tweets = []

        try:
            # call twitter api to fetch tweets
            fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q = query, count = count)

            # parsing tweets one by one
            for tweet in fetched_tweets:
                # empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet
                parsed_tweet = {}

                # saving text of tweet
                parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text
                # saving sentiment of tweet
                parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)

                # appending parsed tweet to tweets list
                if tweet.retweet_count > 0:
                    # if tweet has retweets, ensure that it is appended only once
                    if parsed_tweet not in tweets:
                        tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
                else:
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)

            # return parsed tweets
            return tweets

        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            # print error (if any)
            print("Error : " + str(e))

def main():
    # creating object of TwitterClient Class
    api = TwitterClient()
    # calling function to get tweets
    tweets = api.get_tweets(query = 'Donald Trump', count = 200)

    # picking positive tweets from tweets
    ptweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive']
    # percentage of positive tweets
    print("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ptweets)/len(tweets)))
    # picking negative tweets from tweets
    ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative']
    # percentage of negative tweets
    print("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ntweets)/len(tweets)))
    # percentage of neutral tweets
    print("Neutral tweets percentage:{}%".format(100*(len(tweets) - len(ntweets) - len(ptweets))/len(tweets)))

    # printing first 5 positive tweets
    print("\n\nPositive tweets:")
    for tweet in ptweets[:20]:
        print(tweet['text'])

    # printing first 5 negative tweets
    print("\n\nNegative tweets:")
    for tweet in ntweets[:20]:
        print(tweet['text'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # calling main function
    main()
```

Comment: Train on more data

Comment: Note: your consumer_secret and access_token_secret are meant to be kept secret. I would suggest to generate new ones and invalidate the ones you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm does not follow any classification procedure used in **Machine Learning**, therefore it has **nothing to train**. It is an algorithm based on a very rudimentary statistical procedure, and to execute it it is **required to have bags of words** previously classified by feeling (a bag of positive words and another with negative words).

By following such a rudimentary statistical procedure, classifying words as neutral is extremely complicated. That is why your algorithm does not work well.

Also, enter a rate of retweets greater than 0

```
if tweet.retweet_count> 0 :
```

but that doesn't make any sense if there is no measure of the proportion of retweets in a period of time.

So as it is your algorithm is hardly going to work well. I recommend doing more research on employee word bag word ranking and **tokenization**.

You can check this link for some details: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/building-a-twitter-sentiment-analysis-in-python

Successes and greetings.